# Is there a PHP 5.3.x PPA for 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, php

I currently have an OpenVZ VPS system running 10.04LTS, which I need a newer build of PHP 5.3 on. This is because I use PHP-FPM for all the virtual sites it hosts, and the Lucid build doesn't include this feature. I was previously using a PPA provided by the Nginx packaging team but they've recently discontinued it which leaves me with an old, buggy, vulnerable version of PHP.

Are there any PHP 5.3.x PPAs which are still kept up to date? By searching Launchpad I've found several with version 5.3.5 but this is also terribly old, and I've found Brian Mercer's PPA but the description says that will be disappearing soon as he no longer needs to maintain it for himself.

So are there any PPAs which offer up a backported/upstream version of PHP 5.3.x (i.e. 5.3.13 which is current) including the PHP-FPM setup? Cheers!

edit - I should further explain that as this is OpenVZ and the VPS provider don't yet provide a 12.04 template, I can't upgrade to 12.04LTS, at least not yet. So while this might be a long-term option, it's not an answer to my immediate question :)

Comment: Why not install 12.04 LTS on your VPS?

Comment: The templates aren't available from my VPS provider, at least not yet. And due to OpenVZ being more akin to containers within a shared kernel, it may be a while before the host hardware is on a suitable kernel to virtualise the 3.2.x series kernels that are contained in 12.04.

Comment: 2.6.18 OpenVZ kernel? [Here's the answer to how to upgrade to 12.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/a/130717/58612) ;-)

Comment: Yep, 2.6.18 kernel on what seems to be RHEL5 (or a binary equivalent). Not sure I want to take the step yet for other reasons (assuming I can find a suitable PPA), but I'll certainly bookmark your link as that could be useful, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I found a PHP 5.4 PPA (at ppa:ondrej/php5), and decided to test that with the few webapps I run on that VPS. All seemed well (aside from vBulletin's upgrade system, but I have a workaround for that), so I've skipped the 5.3 series altogether and switched to 5.4. Probably won't be upgrading to 12.04LTS yet, although at least I now know that it's possible, and how to do it :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

ppa:zulcss/php5.3-lucid

ppa:igb/ppa-lucid-testing

Comment: Chuck's is terribly out of date, and the other is listed as "not ready for prime-time" which worries me somewhat. Useful links though, thanks :-)