# Ubuntu 12.04 with 2.6.38 kernel

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

Can I install vanilla kernel 2.6.38 on Ubuntu 12.04?!?

I tried installing it and booted 2.6.38 instead of default kernel but it never boots up.

All I need to know is can I install 2.6 kernel on Ubuntu 12.04?

PS: I dont want GUI access, I am fine with just the console login.

Thanks,
Bala.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you include **why** you want to install an older kernel? This is possible, but you'll have to account for possible other issues arising from installing a different kernel version than supported for your Ubuntu release. You won't be receiving updates as well, so I really would **not recommend** that. Also include what *exact* steps you took to install the other kernel.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply :) I want to debug kernel 2.6.38 using KGDB. Earlier I used to do it with ubuntu 10.10 VM's but since its not supported anymore I thought of movin to Ubuntu 12.04 VM.

Comment: Related, but not really answering *how* to get it working: [What's the minimal compatible Linux kernel version required to run Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/238077/88802). Please **edit** your question to provide the new information, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see. :)