# Are mismatched binaries a supported configuration?

Tags: apt, kernel, updates

Does Ubuntu support systems where the version of the system binaries does not match the kernel/modules version?  I need to know if this is officially supported, not merely "probably OK" or "should work".  In particular, I have a system using Ubuntu 18.04 kernel/modules paired with /lib, /bin, /usr, /etc and such binaries taken from an Ubuntu 16.04 image.

If this is a supported configuration, can you clarify how much mismatch is considered supported?

The only reference on this topic I can find is this question which implies that mismatched binaries are not supported, but does not say so as clearly as I need.  I need a clear statement to answer this for my project.

[What's the minimal compatible Linux kernel version required to run Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238077/whats-the-minimal-compatible-linux-kernel-version-required-to-run-ubuntu)

Comment: Packages form other releases are not officially supported, but may work ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "officially supported"? That Canonical provides phone support whan you purchase the [advantage collection for 150$/Year](https://buy.ubuntu.com/collections/ubuntu-advantage-for-desktop)?

Comment: No I'm betting @Pilot6 wasn't specific to Advantage support, but Xenial (16.04) packages have no guarantee to work on anything but Xenial (as not tested, no-one checked for ABI/API changes so it's all on you). All packages are re-compiled for each release, so ABI breakage will not occur within a release; if you mix up releases then this checking won't have been done and all testing & support is up to person doing it.  It's open source though; so you can grab the source & do the checks, then test yourself if you so wish.