# Cannot start Ubuntu after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04: glibc6 error

Tags: xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did my upgrade to 12.04 fail with “glibc not found” or “libc6” or “requires kernel 2.6.24” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125742/why-did-my-upgrade-to-12-04-fail-with-glibc-not-found-or-libc6-or-requires)

I am not able to start my Linux. Recently I tried to upgrade it from 11.10 to 12.04. Due to some errors it was partially upgraded. But later on I am not able to start linux. It is showing an error "GLIB-6" is missing.. any help...