# Unable to boot my system after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

I was doing upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, It showed some error. Then I restarted the system. Now it's not booting. It's showing the following error when it starts and reboot by itself.

```
sed: /lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
```

please please reply back with some solutions. I am kind of stuck not able to use the system. I need it so badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it.

Here is the link to my answer on another same question:

https://askubuntu.com/a/126542/56649

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. your solution worked as it seems. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer that Andrew gave here : https://askubuntu.com/a/126282/56942. You will need the live cd or live usb.

Comment: Hey I tried but still I am getting the same error almost. but with different required directory                                   sudo: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libpam.so.0
Please help with this issue if you can.. I am kind of stuck... I am kind of naive to ubuntu.

Comment: if you type in a terminal uname -a can you paste the output? I think you have the wrong version maybe have a 32 bit version and trying to install the 64 bit

Comment: I am installing the right version. I have 64-bit and I am installing 64-bit only.

Comment: pzanoni has given a detailed solution of it and it worked as it seems right now. http://askubuntu.com/a/126542/56649