# Matlab can't find /lib/libc.so.6 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, matlab

I'm trying to open Matlab (32 bit version) in 12.04, with

```
matlab -glnx86
```

but it returns

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 1: /usr/local/temp/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
/usr/local/temp/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXpm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? I've seen similar questions where it turned out that the needed library was moved and had to be linked to the right place, but I'm a pretty new user and I don't know how to check for that or fix it.

Comment: those files are provided by `multiarch-support` and they're located in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.  I don't have a copy of Matlab, so I can't test.

Comment: Possible answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125649/reboot-during-update-glibc-error Sorry, no longer using Matlab, so can't test myself.

Comment: OK, after running Update Manager again, it works now. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Worked for me!

Regards

Answer (score 3):

So I received the exact same error after updating from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 both 64bit using matlab 2010a student version. To solve this problem I followed these five steps

1. `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so /lib/libc.so.6`
2. Install `libXpm4:i386`.
3. Install `libXmu6:i386`.
4. Install `libXp6:i386`.
5. Install `libXtst6:i386`.

Here the first step is performed from the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). For the last four steps, I went to the Software Center and searched for the package to be installed (e.g., `libXpm4:i386`) and clicked Install.

A long form version of what led me to these five actions are described below if anyone is interested or runs into a similar but not identical problem and is looking for insight:

As suggested I followed [the instructions for the student version here](http://www.emmalzhang.com/robotTech/2012/05/10/matlab-starting-error-in-ubuntu-12-04-libc-so-6-not-found/). I ran the command:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

With the first error resolved I still had the error about `libXpm.so.4`. I tried to make may different symbolic links to the file `libXpm.so.4` found elsewhere on my system to the one in `/lib` but got the error `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. I think what is going wrong is that I am missing some 32-bit versions of libraries need by the 32-bit Matlab I am running. With this in mind, I went to the Software Center and searched for `libXpm` and installed `libXpm4:i386` which appeared to be a 32-bit version of `libXpm4` which was already installed (`i386` denotes a 32-bit architecture). This solved the last of the two messages above.

Attempting to run Matlab again, I then got a similar error but with `libXmu.so.6` not found. I again went back to the Software Center and searched `libXmu` and installed `libXmu6:i386`. This action solved the new error.

Again running `matlab -glnx86`, I got the error `libXp.so.6 not found`, so I searched for `libXp` in the Software Center and installed `libXp6:i386`. This solved this latest error.

Lastly, I ran `matlab -glnx86` and the splash screen appeared but it quickly closed giving the error `Unable to initialize com.mathworks.mwswing.MJStartup`. After searching the web I found [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9G9AK1/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-9G9AK1), which suggested installing `libXtst` so, one last time, I went to the Software Center and installed `libXtst6:i386`.

I just was trying to get my Matlab working so I do not know exactly why this fixed it but my hypothesis is that the update removed some 32-bit versions of files still needed by Matlab so I just went back and manually re-installed them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

you could try follow this link , I found it helpful.
http://www.emmalzhang.com/robotTech/2012/05/10/matlab-starting-error-in-ubuntu-12-04-libc-so-6-not-found/
MATLAB Starting Error in Ubuntu 12.04: libc.so.6: not found

Comment: Please add necessary information on the answer

Answer (score 2):

From the [official page](http://www.mathworks.es/support/solutions/en/data/1-F68FSA/index.html?solution=1-F68FSA/):

**Subject**:

Why do I get a libc.so.6: not found error when launching MATLAB in Ubuntu?

**Problem Description**:

I get the following error when I run MATLAB in Ubuntu:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/util/oscheck.sh: 605: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
```

**Solution**:

To resolve this problem, open a Terminal window and use the commands below depending on your OS architecture:

For 64-bit Ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

For using the Student Version on 64-bit:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib
```

Afterwards try starting MATLAB again.

Answer (score 0):

For missing `libXp.so.6`, add:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

then run

```
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install libxp6
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out a workaround. When I run `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/matlab`, nothing happens, only the first screen of MATLAB is shown and then disappears.

If I choose "Run in Terminal", the error message appears in a terminal window, BUT, the difference is that MATLAB launches and works.

This is far from perfect, but at least lets me run the program.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please only use the Answer section for *actual answers*. If you have a *new* question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: **Jugurtha**: It seems like *part* of this is an answer, in that you're saying that using "Run in Terminal" is a workaround that gets MATLAB to launch. I recommend editing out anything that *isn't* an answer. (You might still want to post a new question, in accordance with @FEichinger's suggestion.) Please also make clear whether any changes have to be made before, in order for this workaround to be effective.